# Need help to fetch rows from oracle DB based on timestamp

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to write sql query for the following scenario. It would be great if can get any help on it.

Scenario :

I have a table(emp) which has three columns id,time and value. There is no primary key in the table. time is a date column holding date and timestamp.

Table will be started to update from afternoon onwards. So table will have yesterday data in it from morning to afternoon. Before inserting current data in it all the yesterday's rows will be cleared and  table will be start to be updated dynamically from noon till evening .But I need to run  the query running from morning onwards and my query should not fetch yesterday's data. So from morning to afternoon I should ideally wait for data to come and should not fetch any rows and start to fetch once the current date data was inserted into it.

I need to run the query for every five minutes and when I run the query I should get all the latest rows in the table so that whenever there is a update in the table those rows will be fetched .

For example when the table is updated from 1 PM onwards. I should get all the rows when i start the first query and after five minutes when i once again run the same query at 1.05 i should get all the rows inserted between 1PM and 1.05PM.

My idea :

Select max(time) from emp;

At the start of the day I should check the max time in the table and it will be definitely yesterday date so I will set today date(2018-07-14 00:00:00) in a local variable or if it's today's date then that value will be stored in the local variable.

I can also do the same in the above query by comparing it with sysdate like below query but not sure about the performance as I saw it took time by comparing with all the rows I guess. See the modified above query below

select max(time) from emp where time = sysdate;

After getting the max time from the table , will have it one variable say lastquerytime, then query the table which has rows greater than this time stamp so that we can fetch all the latest rows for every five minutes.

Select id,time,value from emp where time > lastquerytime;

So the idea is getting all the rows and check the maximum timestamp in it and query the table next time with rows having timestamp greater than this max timestamp. Like this need to do the same for every five minutes till the end of the day.

Now I am using two queries to achieve this scenario.
Any suggestions for better approach and queries to write for this scenario will help me a lot.

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output by editing the question.

Comment: Should running the query just after midnight pick up the last few minutes of unseen data from yesteday? Or are those lost and never retrieved? Which yould also happen if the first update for today wipes out yesterday's data before a query has seen it. Not sure I quite understand your model.

Comment: The problem is unclear. You'd like to run the query periodically (every 5 minutes) and just get the new data? Data that was added after last run? Is data added always with current time (i.e. `SYSDATE` is used to fill `TIME` column)? What type is the `TIME` column? A `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` or what?

Comment: @Hilarion :Yes periodically query should run every 5 minutes to get the latest rows. Yes data will be added with current date and time . Even though i have date column it will have both date and timestamp value in it.  For example at 1 PM when i ran the query it should fetch all the rows in the table. When i again query after 5 mins i.e. 01.05 PM it should fetch the rows inserted between 1.00 PM and 1.05 PM. Similarly it should continue till the end of the day.Hope i tried to make it clear for you. If not please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like to get data from yesterday:

```
SELECT id,time,value FROM emp WHERE time BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1/86400
```

Comment: Your second queery isn't Oracle syntax. I'm not sure this is what the question is about though; the sysdate check is seeing if the latest data is from today or yesterday, not looking for all data from yesterday (as that will be wiped out anyway, apparently).

Comment: @AlexPoole, second example is removed. And yes, in general the question is not very clear

Comment: Ok let me rephrase the question .. Table will be started to update at afternoon only by deleting all the yesterday's data and today's data will be inserted . But my query should run from morning onwards Which should not retrieve yesterday's data and start to retrieve only today's data and that should happenwhen today's data was inserted i.e. afternoon ..this is what I tried to explain above

Comment: So between morning and afternoon, there will be no data for today. As the query is supposed to be run since morning, it will be returning nothing until afternoon. And then it will return everything. And then what? New data is being added through the afternoon, or is data fed just once a day? Is the query still being run, after it returned the data, or will it "pause" until next morning? Still very unclear. And please remember to also edit the original question, when providing additional information, so anyone can attempt at the issue, without having to read through all the comments.

Comment: @hilarion :Yeah edited the question . Thanks for your suggestion. Yes after that we need continuously fetch the updated rows from afternoon onwards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all rows on the maximum date of the table.

If so:

```
select e.*
from emp
where time >= (select trunc(max(time)) from emp);
```

If you want the results based on clock-time, then you would use `trunc(sysdate)` instead.